# Tailwindcss @layer directive does not work in ReactJS/ViteJS Project

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, tailwind-in-js

I have created a react app use vitejs with the following setup:

```
- index.html
- index.css
- main.js
- App.css
- App.js
```

This setup works as follows:

- `index.html` uses `main.js` (i.e., `<script src="/src/main.js" type="module"></script>`)
- `main.js` imports BOTH `index.css` AND `App.js`
- `App.js` imports `App.css`.

Now, what I would like to do is use the tailwind `@layer` directive as follows:

```
@layer components {
  .some-class-name {
   @apply [tailwind classes]
 } 
}
```

Now, this works inside of `index.css`:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .header {
    @apply bg-purple-500;
  }
}
```

That will add a purple background in the components layer of tailwind css.  Furthermore, if I want to override that class with a tailwind-css class I can:

```
<div className="header bg-green-600">Header</div>
```

In this instance the background will be green, not purple.

However, this does not work in `App.css`

```
@layer components {
  .header {
    @apply bg-purple-500;
  }
}
```

In this case, the background does NOT turn purple.

I am wondering, how can I get the `@layer` directive to work in the `App.css` file (just like it does in the `index.css` file.

Thanks.